# Datatables shows two paginators

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm implementing pagination because of performance, When I started working with a lot of registers, my browser just hungs a lot of time. Seems like I'm doing ok with configuration but still getting two sets of paginators (it should be one of course), one sems to be controlling laravel pagination, the other one seems to control datatables pagination. Something very simple, but I'm stucked there.

I include the screen capture.

[Two paginators, one for from laravel links the other from Datatables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtqeV.jpg)

Maybe I'm taking the wrong aproach, is there something like getting each data page with ajax or something like that?

Part of my AppServiceProvider.php

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        Paginator::useBootstrapFour();
```

Part of My Index File

```
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="table" 
                        class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Centro de costos</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Activo</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($almacenes as $key=>$almacen)
                                <tr data-id="{{$almacen->id}}">
                                    <td>{{ $almacen->nombre }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $almacen->centrocosto->nombre }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $almacen->descripcion}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @php
                                            if  ($almacen->activo==0)
                                            {
                                                echo '<span class="label label-inverse">NO</span';
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                echo '<span class="label label-info">SI</span>';                                                        
                                            }
                                        @endphp
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <a href="{{ route('almacenes.edit', $almacen->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                                            <a href="{{ route('almacenes.destroy', $almacen->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {!! $almacenes->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') !!}
                </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        order: [[0, 'desc']],
    });
});
```

Part of my controller file

```
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $almacene = Almacene::find($id);
        $centrocostos = Centrocosto::all();

        return view('almacene.edit', compact('almacene','centrocostos'));
    }
```

Part of My model

```
class Almacene extends Model {          
    static $rules = ['centrocosto_id' => 'required',        
                        'nombre' => 'required',
                    'activo' => 'required',     ];      
    protected $perPage = 20;
```

Obviously, If I don't use the $perPage attribute Laravel paginates by 15 rows.  So I get My set of Pages Divided too, Laravel is controlling the subset fo 20 in this case, and Dataset is controlling the default subset of 10. But, thats the second problem.

I have changed the type of paginator, deleting {!! $almacenes->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') !!} to give control to Datatables (which makes my browser do the 6000 rows job and being very slow to load), changing the version of bootstrap, change my version of datatables, look for answer around the WEB, here,etc... I'm really lost.

Comment: Remove `{!! $almacenes->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') !!}`

You already have the datatable which will display the pagination it self

oR Remove ` $('#table').DataTable({
        order: [[0, 'desc']],
    });` 

Also Please follow https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination that how to implement pagination

Comment: Thanks a lot @Punit Gajjar, I will read the document. I already did the thinks you say, actually I've edited the post.